# Stream Youtube with mpv starting at an arbitrary point later in the video

Tags: streaming, youtube, mpv

I prefer streaming Youtube videos via `mpv`,

```
mpv https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video-id>
```

However, for long videos sometimes the audio breaks down in the middle, leaving error messages like

> ```
> [ffmpeg] tls: Error in the pull function.
> ```

Restarting the video is starting it from the beginning. How can I either directly in the command line start from, let's say, minute 30, or alternatively jump in the `mpv` interface to minute 30 *without* pressing 30 times the up button (which also has issues if done too fast)?

I haven't found an answer related to that issue in the man page. Is it possible at all?

Also alternative suggestions for streaming are welcome.

Comment: Yes, [Tumbleweed badge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/tumbleweed)!!

Answer (score 4):

Get a decent cache with [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) (to avoid the issue in the first place)

```
youtube-dl.py -q -f "(137/136)+(141/140)" "$URL"
```

Play the cache with any player ([ffplay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html), [vlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/), [omxplayer](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer), [c2play](https://github.com/OtherCrashOverride/c2play), [mpv](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#playback-control), etc)
If you still want to seek;

```
ffplay -ss 30:00 *.mp4
```

.

```
vlc --start-time=1800 *.mp4
```

.

```
omxplayer --pos 00:30:00 *.mp4
```

.

```
c2play --time 00:30:00.00 *.mp4
```

.

```
mpv --start=30:00 *.mp4
```

Comment: What is the `-f "(137/136)+(141/140)"` format option for `youtube-dl` doing? Could you elaborate on that part?

Comment: @jjdb  the man/help page will tell you all about -f but but basically its selecting the mp4 format from the youtube API. ( see "Comparison of YouTube media encoding options " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_formats )

Comment: Still, the code is cryptic to me. And also: As far as I understand it, your proposal essentially involves a download that has to be removed later. So it is not actually a streaming solution, is it?

Comment: @jjdb clearly my answer offers both options, obviously if streaming is unreliable a more stable cache can be used and can be scripted to automatically remove the file when done.

Comment: Well, it is not really a streaming solution, as I have to wait for the whole video to be downloaded in order to be able to play it correctly: with `mpv`, audio does not work properly.

Comment: Usually you can play a file that is beeing downloaded separately (this is a "hand made" cache)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `--start=MM:SS` to start your video at MM minutes SS seconds.

For example:

```
mpv --start=45:00 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video-id>'
```

Will start the video at 45 minutes.

Comment: I've tried the command, but my connection is lousy at the moment, so it didn't work. I'll try later again. So far it works fine for say 1 minute into the video, but 20 or so is too much already. `[cache] Cache is not responding - slow/stuck network connection?` is the error message

Comment: In this case you might want to first download the video with a tool like [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) for example, then play it with `mpv` at the wanted location.

Comment: Do you know of another way to increase the cache size, or to improve cache handling?

Comment: You can change the cache size with `--cache` and some other options (see the man page)